# Programmatically adding UIButtons and UIImages to a UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've modified Apple's [Scrolling](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) example to grab a series of images created from files referenced in `CoreData` objects. I can add the images fine, but I also want to programmatically add a `UIButton` to each image. The number of images depends on the number of `CoreData` objects, so I can't use IB.

Can anyone give me some help on how I would best implement this?

Here's the code that grabs the images from the `CoreData` store:

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    Sentence *testSentence = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:i];

    NSArray *paths       = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *imageName = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[testSentence image]];
    NSLog(@"imageName: %@", imageName);

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
    NSLog(@"image: %@", image);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    NSLog(@"imageView: %@", imageView);

    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    // setup each frame to a default height and width, it will be properly placed when we call "updateScrollList"
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.tag = i;  // tag our images for later use when we place them in serial fashion
    [scrollView1 addSubview:imageView];

    [image release];
    [imageView release];
}

[self layoutScrollImages];  // now place the photos in serial layout within the scrollview
```

And here's the code that lays the images out in the scrollview:

```
- (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

// set the content size so it can be scrollable
[scrollView1 setContentSize:CGSizeMake((kNumImages * kScrollObjWidth), [scrollView1 bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your problem. Couldn't you just do this?

```
...
 imageView.frame = rect;
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
aButton.frame = imageView.frame;
[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(whatever:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[imageView addSubview:aButton];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yup that works - but I can't click on the button  (it steadfastly ignores my clicks / taps - yes I've changed the action), and I want a button that isn't the same size as the imageView.frame. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably mean `aButton.frame = imageView.bounds`, although in this case I don't think it matters much. You might also have to set imageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES (the default is NO for UIImageView, IIRC).

Comment: Sorted out the button / imageframe size thanks - but I can't get it to click at all. I've tried: 
[aButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; [aButton setEnabled:YES]; [aButton setAlpha:1];
and I can't seem to make any headway. Is there a way to debug what you're clicking? Any strategies to get things working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue where I was creating an image gallery and the buttons I added to each thumbnail would not respond to TouchUpInside events.

I was able to get it working by creating a custom UIView subclass to hold each individual image and implementing touchesBegan:withEvent: and touchesEnded:withEvent: in that subclass.

See the [UIScrollView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomingByTouch/ZoomingByTouch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH4-SW3) for sample code.

If you aren't allowing zooming on the UIScrollView you can simplify the code by assuming every touch end is a single touch event.